# Simple way to duct a PVC pipe through a stainless steel sheet cover

Tags: civil-engineering, pipelines

I need to duct a PVC pipe (DN80) through a stainless steel sheet metal covering. The hole thing needs to be tight against stormwater. There's tons of products to duct pipes through thick walls, but I'm at loss on how to do that here. The cover is horizontal, upside checkered. Ideas I've considered:

- Welding a short stainless steel pipe stub onto the sheet and use a ring seal
- Hole with ID of pipe in steel sheet, flange the pipe through the sheet

Both of these appear overblown to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this would typically be achieved, is with an off-the-shelf "Tank Connector". This essentially replaces the welding operation in your first idea. Simply cut the appropriately sized hole, and install the connector. There are face seals on both sides of the sheet metal, which are clamped tight.

[image: Tank Connector]

I've shown a brass connector, since I thought it was the clearest image - but needless to say, these are available in PVC, Stainless Steel, and with any number of diameters or Male/Female/Etc. configurations, according to your exact needs.